# Alamofire not working (Swift/Xcode 8)

Tags: ios, swift2, alamofire, xcode8

I am getting the following errors when trying to import Alamofire into my project (Cocoapods isn't working for me, so I have to manually import it).

Anyway, I'm using XCode 8 and Swift 2.3, and I'm getting these errors:

[image: Use of unresolved identifier kSecTrustResultProceed]

[image: Contextual type AnyObject cannot be used with array literal]

Update: I cleaned XCode, downloaded the latest version of Alamofire and restarted my computer. Now, XCode seems to be giving me conflicting errors (pictures for reference)
[image: Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type String]
[image: Value of optional type String? not unwrapped]
Thanks!

Comment: I would suggest downloading the most recent Alamofire and adding it into the project to see if the error goes away. Also with issues like this it helps to clean the project and restart your computer.

Comment: What version of Alamofire are you using?

Comment: I'm downloading the one found at the link here: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Comment: Could you provide the screen shot of the error screen?

Comment: I think they're in my original post(?)

Comment: Exact same errors here. Xcode beta 2. When I run it on my previous Xcode version (7) it's working fine, even with the same version of swift.

Answer (score 15):

As of early September '16, you need to use the following in your Podfile:

```
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :tag => '3.5.0'
```

Pointing to the swift2.3 branch no longer works, as that branch has been deleted. The tag '3.5.0' points to the last revision on master that supports Swift 2.3.

Comment: swift2.3 does NOT exit and it is correct. But it is Not solving the issue. Still having the error of Unresolved identifier !!

Answer (score 4):

Use Swift 2.3 in Xcode 8

[image]

[image]

Pod file

```
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
use_frameworks!


target 'ProjectName' do
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'Contentful'
    pod 'ContentfulDeliveryAPI'
end

post_install do |installer|
    installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '2.3'
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Which version of `cocoapods` are you using?

Comment: this solution is NOT making any difference. Still getting unresolved identifier !

Comment: still gives the same 3 errors of Unresolved identifier !!

Answer (score 1):

More information about Xcode 8 + Swift 2.3 support for Alamofire:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/pull/1313

Try updating your pod to 
`pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :tag => '3.5.0'` (Updated)

Update: This is a good guide to follow if you're interested in keeping Xcode7 compatibility, and still be able to target iOS10/swift 2.3 for development: http://radex.io/xcode7-xcode8/

Comment: I'm not sure if your solution works, but I basically realised that all pods written in Swift were causing me errors, so I switched from Alamofire to AFNetworking and so on.

Comment: It does work, I'm doing this. I had to do the same for 'AlamofireImage'; but they have a 'swift2.3' branch for it too.

Comment: Worked for me! Just need to make sure you use Swift 2.3, not 2.2, and pull the right branch from Alamofire

Comment: The podfile needed to be `pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => 'swift2.3'` for me

Comment: No Upstream branch !

Comment: this solution is NOT working for me. XCode 8. Alamofire 3.5.0 and Swift 2.3.
There is NO upstream branch for swift2.3 and or swift3 as of Oct 17 2016 !! Is there another way ?