# issue while installing pod by command line

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am using pods first time in the project . I created a new project and followed following process :

1. Downloaded master from the github ,as terminal asked me to do it manually
2. fired : **pod init** method . This command generated  Podfile in my Xcode project folder
3. Then I added a line in the pod file : `pod 'Alamofire', '2.0.2'`

4 . Then I fired `pod install` command and I am getting following error in the terminal window :

```
Setting up CocoaPods master repo
[!] Unable to add a source with url `https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git` named `master-1`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

I am following this tutorial :
https://www.raywenderlich.com/97014/use-cocoapods-with-swift
Please suggest workaround for this issue.
following is my pod file :

```
platform :ios, "8.0"
 use_frameworks!
target 'PodsTest' do
  # Uncomment this line if you're using Swift or would like to use dynamic frameworks
  # use_frameworks!

  # Pods for PodsTest
  pod 'Alamofire', '2.0.2'
  target 'PodsTestTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

  target 'PodsTestUITests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

Comment: step-4 should be pod install command

Comment: yeah , thats by mistake , I edited my question

Comment: how you have mentioned the pod command for Alamofire in Pod file? Can you tell me that? @V-Xtreme

Comment: Can you tell me you xcode version?

Comment: @EktaMakadiya: Version 8.0

Comment: Try following steps from Github : https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#installation

Comment: In you pod file mention the code like this.

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '2.0.2'

Comment: checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38222229/alamofire-not-working-swift-xcode-8

Comment: Its not working for AFNetwork also : target 'PodsTest' do
   pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
end

Comment: see this https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/4293

Comment: @V-Xtreme Kindly find my answer and respond.

Answer (score 1):

In you pod file mention the code like this.

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '2.0.2'
```

and then try pod install

Comment: I am using the same. For me it is working. Or try 2.0.0 instead of 2.0.2. Also try without target 'PodTests' do @V-Xtreme

Answer (score 1):

You just need to update repo

Run `pod repo update` on terminal.

Try to use latest Alamofire => `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'`

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Are your Command Line Tools set up correctly according to the Xcode version you are using?

In Terminal:

sudo xcode-select -r

And then in XCode:

Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Command Line Tools

worthwhile checking, this might cause the problem